# Torque in different car gears?

Tags: torque, engines

Recently I have been researching torque and horsepower.  I know that the lower the car gear, the more the torque.  However, whenever I see specifications of a car, it says :

> *X lb-ft of torque at Y rpm.*

Now, shouldn't they specify the gear that was measured in? Or is this the torque the engine makes, measured before the gearbox?

I am a little confused, I would be happy if you could help me with some explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The torque indicated by the car manufacturer is usually measured at the engine's output, without use of the gearbox.
However it is still a good indicator of the car's global performance, but only if you pay attention to which rpm provides the higher torque.

Example : 100 Nm @3000 rpm is a better performance than 100 Nm @7000 rpm since the first one is available in "normal" driving while the second is available pushing the engine very high in rpm which only occurs in automobile sports or "unlawful" driving.